# After using fscanf to get to a specific line, how to read that entire line?

Tags: c

I have a text file like below. I use fscanf to read until it sees "found", and then read everything else in that line into an array.

```
text text some words text 
text hello text text
text text random text
world

found read1 read2 read3
don't
read any of this
```

So far I have the following):

```
while(fscanf(file, "%s", var) != EOF){
    if(strcmp(var, "found") == 0){
        //put 'read1' 'read2' 'read3' into an array
    }
}
```

How do I just read until the end of that line? Thanks

Comment: A [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) could come in handy. Especially the [input/output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) section, and its [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io#Functions). I'm sure you'll find something appropriate soon.

Comment: `if(strcmp(var, "found")){` --> `if(strcmp(var, "found")==0){`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah yes, apologies for that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fgets` function will read until the end of line or file - whichever comes first! It will read from your current file read point.

[Here's some documentation for fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), with an excerpt:

```
char line[LINE_MAX];
while (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, file) != NULL) {
..
}
```

**Edit:**
Then use a string operation on the line to extract what you want. Either [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) or [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) would be OK places to start. I quite like [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) too.

Comment: Hi noelicus. But how to store each character 'read1' 'read2' 'read3' as separate elements in a char **?

Comment: @novice This well answers the post's questions "how to read that entire line?" and "How do I just read until the end of that line?".  Now the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746053/after-using-fscanf-to-get-to-a-specific-line-how-to-read-that-entire-line#comment80441701_46746119) is starting a new question.  New questions (going beyond the original post) belong in another post.  If "how to store each character 'read1' 'read2' 'read3'" was important, it should  have been in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
fgets (name, 50, stdin);
```

`50` is the max length of the buffer.

2.

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);
```

The `[]` is the scanset character. `[^\n]` tells that while the input is not a newline `'\n'` take input. Then with the `%*c` it reads the newline character from the input buffer (which is not read), and the `*` indicates that this read in input is discarded (assignment suppression), as you do not need it.

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` does not work well if the the line is only `"\n"`  or too long.  Stick with `fgets()`.